# py.test does not extract data from the database

Tags: python, database, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

Good afternoon.

I'm testing api based on django-rest-framework using [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/). As far as I knew at the beginning of the test, py.test creates a duplicate database with the prefix test_. But the pattern during writing tests noticed that it is not receiving data from the database. That is a duplicate of this supposedly empty. 
A simple example:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_db():
    qs = Category.objects.get(id=4)
    assert qs['id'] = 4
```

Its returns this error below, but in a database, object with id=4 exists.

```
>       assert qs['id'] == 4
E       assert [] == 4
```

I am new to testing, may miss something, help please.

Comment: It creates an *empty* duplicate database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Daniel commented, test DB is initially empty. You can add any data you want for testing by using one of two methods:

1. [Django Fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#topics-testing-fixtures) - You can add data using a JSON file just like initial data.
2. Mock data using a library such as [django dynamic fixture](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture) during run time.

These are your best bets.